How to design a variational surrogate for $\|\mathbf{x}\|_{\infty}$ of vectors?
How to design a variational surrogate for $\|\mathbf{x}\|_{\infty}$ of vectors?
I've been learning optimization theory recently and came across this problem. It's not easy for me to come up with a proper algorithm for this problem.

Perhaps you can elaborate on what you want to do.
